# What happens if I press the Button in a Stack Setup on a 2960-X?

Tags: cisco, switch, stacking

Someone recently push the Mode button for too long and the Switch Stack restarted in Express Setup.
Is this the normal behavior on the Mode Button?
Where were debating that the Whole Stack was not supposed to erase or not if the  button was press for to long.
One of my colleagues told me that the next Stack member should maintain the configuration as the master and only the one that was pressed was the only that will take enter the Express Setup config.
I can't find any documentation about the specific case
For my understanding I tough that they should all take a dump if you hold the Mode button on the Master Stack Switch.
Do anybody know the answer on this case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Holding the button in for 10 seconds or more is basically the same thing as performing a factory reset.   I would hope somebody has the configuration backed up somewhere and can easily dump it back on the switch.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the factory reset will be performed on all 3 Switches on the Stack?
Thanks